# How transform that query in column json with postgresql query builder of typeorm?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I have one table "knowledge_tracks" with two fields of type jsonb in postgresql. In the project i need to make query in that fields. I managed make to query on the console of pgadmin, but i need use that in my project with typeorm. It's possible?
My query:

```
SELECT
     id,
     branches.item_object as branches,
     position_office.item_object as position_office
FROM knowledge_tracks,
     jsonb_array_elements(branches) with ordinality branches(item_object, position),
     jsonb_array_elements(positions) with ordinality position_office(item_object, position)
WHERE id = 'id_knowledge_tracks'
AND branches.item_object->>'id' in ('id_branche_1', 'id_branche_2')
AND position_office.item_object->>'id' in ('id_position_office')
```

The model of data is similar the this:

```
knowledge_tracks.knowledge_tracks=[
  {id:"knowledge_track_1"},
  {id:"knowledge_track_2"}
]
knowledge_tracks.position_office=[
  {id:"id_position_office_1"},
  {id:"id_position_office_2"}
]
```

Comment: Use your query as native in typeorm. Why use a query builder with cryptic proprietary syntax to build a query that you have already built?

Comment: I think this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and could be better solved by changing your schema. It seems like you're storing lists of associated items in JSON rather than using join tables. Branches and positions seem to contain lists of associated items. Instead, consider instead using normal foreign keys and [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). That will be faster, safer, and work better with TypeORM. If you show us your full schema, perhaps we can suggest a better schema.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm thanks for your answer, in this case i thought to use the resource of pagination of typeorm, therefore i am using the querybuilder.

Comment: You might want to see [these](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/) pagination techniques in SQL then. The offset/limit one is pretty simple to use.

Comment: @Schwern Thank you by opinion, i think will follow your suggestion, i am change the schema. Tks

Comment: That's a good idea to rewrite the schema. [Here's an article about how to work with JSONB in TypeORM](https://wanago.io/2020/12/28/nestjs-json-postgresql-typeorm/) should it come up again. Note how they made an interface for the JSONB columns.